# Combining range and script filter in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do the following, but this results in a null_pointer_exception.

What I want to achieve is the results between a range (standalone this works) and filter all saturdays. However I have tried combining filters. So is there a way to combine these filters or should I go for an alternative solution?

```
"query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": []
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "myDateField": {
                        "from": "2015-10-09 00:00:00",
                        "to": "2015-12-31 00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "script": {
                    "script": ["doc['myDateField'].date.dayOfWeek == 6"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments to @Richa's answer, the `filtered` query is [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html), too. You should just remove it all and simply use `bool/filter` containing a `range` and a `script` filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "myDateField": {
              "from": "2015-10-09 00:00:00",
              "to": "2015-12-31 00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": [
              "doc['myDateField'].date.dayOfWeek == 6"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version is < 2.x. Use `bool filter` to combine multiple queries:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "range": {
              "myDateField": {
                 "from": "2015-10-09 00:00:00",
                 "to": "2015-12-31 00:00:00"
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "script": {
              "script": [
                 "doc['myDateField'].date.dayOfWeek == 6"
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

`Filters` have been deprecated in 2.x version. You can use `Bool Query` to achieve the same.

Comment: Note that the [`filtered` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) is deprecated, too. You should just remove it all and just use `bool/filter` containing `range` and `script`

Comment: @val can you give an example?

Comment: Let's give @Richa a few minutes, then I'll kick in.